# Windows 10 won’t log in and can’t be reset or enter safe mode. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

I restarted my Windows 10 Home laptop after uninstalling a programme, but when it restarted the log in screen was different from usual. Instead of the box asking for my pin, there was a button saying “sign in” which opened a internet connected window first asking for my password and then 2FA. Everything seemed like it worked, but the screen went black then booted me out to the log in screen again. It kept happening when I tried again. I know for certain I’m entering the correct password because I’ve quadruple checked it by logging in on my phone. It’s definitely the correct password and email address. My keyboard works fine because I clicked the eye to check I was typing the correct characters.

So far, I have tried holding shift  on the restart button at the log in page. From there I’ve tried booting into safe mode, but the log in screen doesn’t come up. My log in screen saver is there, but no accounts or even buttons come up to shut down or restart.

I’ve also tried choosing a restore point but it asks me to log in and won’t accept my password even though it’s correct. I tried choosing Start Up Repair but I get the same results as the previous. I tried command prompt, but it boots me out to the log in screen after a brief black screen and then strange light patterns on my screen. I’ve also tried booting from an anti-virus rescue environment USB but I get a black screen with some white writing that says something along the lines of there being no readable volume. I tried to reset the PC too, but it again asks me for the password and then tells me it’s incorrect when it’s definitely correct, or it goes through a 2FA screen successfully but then kicks me back out to a log in screen.

I only have the one administrator account on my computer, which is the one I can’t log in to. There are no other users and I can’t get into command prompt to enable the local admin account.

My other issue, is that I don’t have any access to another computer except my Raspberry Pi running Unbuntu, which won’t successfully download a Windows 10 image so I can create recovery media, and the Windows media creation tool can’t be downloaded to it.

I’m at a complete loss as to what to do at this stage. I have no idea what else I can try to gain access to my computer again considering I can’t even reset it successfully. I’m not even sure how this problem has occurred.

I’d really appreciate any solutions that I can try that could help me fix this problem with Windows 10.

Comment: See [8 ways to boot into Windows 10 Safe Mode](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10/). Method 2 seems like the one to try (for method 8 there's only a slight chance for it to work).

Comment: Use the RPI to download and create an ISO for a bootable Linux USB, in the meantime. BTW, could that "programme" have been malware, and it's trying to steal credentials, not log you in?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the link. My problem isn’t that I can’t boot into safe mode, but that when it does try to boot into safe mode, the login screensaver comes up but with no way to log in. I’ve tried several different ways, including method 2, all with the same result.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik As I said in my description, my RPi keeps failing when trying to download an iso so that’s not working for me either. Also, the programme was Malwarebytes Anti-Malware which I’ve never had an issue before, have been using for years and downloaded through the website. I uninstalled it because I no longer need it and it was conflicting with Bitdefender.

Comment: A possible hack might be to boot a Linux live DVD and rename the file containing the screensaver. Some Linux distributions are pretty small.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the suggestion! I managed to find an old Ubuntu drive lying around, so I’ve booted from that and am currently copying over any files I can access to another drive (surprised it actually booted). I didn’t try renaming the file, but I’m not so bothered about Windows being corrupted now that I know my files are safe (I hadn’t backed up in a few months). I didn’t even think about doing that until you mentioned the Linux live DVD. I can just run that until I can get access to reinstalling Windows. Though it’s a pain to be missing certain software. Thanks again.

Comment: In that case I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible hack might be to boot a Linux live DVD and rename the file containing the screensaver.

While booting up in Linux, you could also backup any unsaved files before doing
dangerous manipulations.

If once the screensaver is disabled Windows can manage to boot, everything is
perhaps fine, but better check by doing
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
I any problems are found, I suggest doing
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
once you are in a situation to create a Windows boot media with the latest Windows version.